# apache virtual host with laravel 5 "Internal error 500"

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, laravel-5

I want to learn laravel, and recently installed a fresh copy laravel on an amazon ec2 instance through composer `composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel-app` with apache2, and php installed.  I configure the conf.d file to change the document root to laravel-folder/public, when i try to go to the public ip address it show a server 500 error.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

    #elastic IP address
    ServerName 42.66.33.52 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot laravel-app/public

    <Directory laravel-app/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted

    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

I've tried `chmod 777` to the entire laravel folder and changed the url in app.php to `42.66.33.52`, and it still showing the same error. I'm new to laravel, and I hope someone can point me to the right direction. I've host other PHP website from this server without using laravel framework and it is function normally.

Comment: Did you try to use full path in DocumentRoot? Did you do chmod 777 with -R (recursive)? Check permissions of /storage folder (it and all files in it should have 775 or 777). Also, what apache error log says?

Comment: oh wow thanks it work now i must have not use -R.  Thanks alot.  by the way is it safe to have everything with 777?

Comment: @DatTran I would rather 775 instead of 777, if you want to use this site on your production server (i.e. public/internet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `chmod -R 775` on `/storage` folder and all files in it.

Answer (score 0):

as @Alexey Mezenin said, you should change the chmod of storage and all files inside by `-R`, and also don't forget to do the same with the `bootstrap/cache` folder. Check that on "Directory Permissions" in the official laravel documentation installation :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation

hope that help ;) Regards.